# Under Cabinet led strip lights appear to be different colors/temperatures

Tags: led, light, cabinets

I have been in my home for about a year. My wife just noticed that the led strip lights under our cabinets in the kitchen are all the same except in one location, where they are less "white" and more "yellow". I don't recall the colors being this different in the past. Is it possible  for them to fade or change?

We don't have any remote or programming, they plug into a brick in an outlet under the sink and it looks like there is wiring connecting multiple strips in different locations.

Is this something I can somehow change, can these change on their own? Or is it likely somehow a strip preset to a different color temperature got mixed in?

Side note - not sure if it is related, we had flickering lights in a few places (not the one place where it looks more yellow) - is it possible for some type of damage?

It's a bit hard to capture the light in photos, but here is the diff between two area taken from the same position in the room

[image: yellowish light example]

[image: brighter/whiter light example]

Comment: Some led lights have settings fir selecting the color. Usually done during the install.

Comment: The vast majority of such LED strip lights are cheap junk where the supplier may not have access to consistent color "bins" (nor care much about such details - they may well be using quality-control rejects from suppliers of far more expensive and consistent lighting products, for instance.)

Comment: It's virtually impossible to capture light in photos unless you have a reference card in the shot.   But you may have captured the difference.

Comment: Do you think I can just buy better lights and use the existing wiring? I think there are simple strips - there is one orange and one black going to each led strip. There doesn't seem to be an IR receiver anywhere to program them. Conversely, can I just buy a new white led light strip program it, then cut it and solder is on to these existing wire connections?

Answer (score 1):

### It varies *dramatically* by dimming/color-control method

If we're dealing with multiple modules listening to the same remote, that is a very different picture than common PWM control. If I'm sounding like Geordi LaForge on Star Trek, then you see the problem. There's a lot of tech here.

And I gather from your question that you don't really have the vernacular to get down-and-dirty on the gory details of this system's design.  That, however, is where the problem lies.

### If you're dealing with RGBWW or simply WW (adjustable color temp)

- in WW's case, that means 2 separate strings, one Warm White and one Cool White.
- in RGBWW's case, it has that, *plus*, Red, Green and Blue.

Typically each of these 2-5 strings is dimmed individually, resulting in a blend of colors. Blending cool white and warm white gives you any color temperature you want, and of course R, G and B let you get funky!

If that's the setup, it's possible that one of the strings has gone out, leaving the remaining string stuck at full-cold or full-warm.  The "flickering" would be consistent with that.

If so, that's likely a simple wire repair.

Comment: Pretty sure these are just White lights. I actually have a light strip with a remote that is rgb, but I can't quite figure out what is going on here. There is no remote sensor. There is a transformer plugged into and outlet and then some type of coupler to multiple  wires, this then travels to different places underneath. I didn't see any type of IR receiving LED. If there are adjustable or programmable I don't see how I would do that with what they put in.

Comment: @HelpEric Interesting. Well, many LED lights actually have a "cool/warm" switch on them that allows you to select color temp with a mechanical switch.  It's the same deal with 2 banks of LEDs, some warm white others cool white.  They're meant to be set-and-forget, so you can match to existing lights or tune color-temp after-the-fact.  Maybe those have that feature and either a) the switch got flipped or b) something broke.